# Element with the most votes for each combination of attributes

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, count, greatest-n-per-group

In my schema, a user can vote for different monsters that have different powers (eg lighting, fire) and different bodies.
Body is a polymorphic association, as it can be from different types of animals.
Here's the relevant pieces of the schema:

```
votes:
monster_id
power_id
body_id #polymorphic association
body_type #polymorphic association
```

For every combination of power and body with representation on the votes table, I want to find out the monsters that got the most votes.

Eg of a specific example:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| votes                                          |
--------------------------------------------------
| monster_id| power_id | body_id | body_type     |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1         | 1        | 1       | Body::Mammal  |
| 2         | 1        | 1       | Body::Mammal  |
| 2         | 1        | 1       | Body::Mammal  |
| 11        | 2        | 11      | Body::Reptile |
| 11        | 2        | 11      | Body::Reptile |
| 22        | 2        | 11      | Body::Reptile |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Results I would like:

```
- ["For the combination (power_id: 1, body_id: 1, body_type: Body::Mammal), the monster with most votes is monster_id: 2",
"For the combination (power_id: 2, body_id: 11, body_type: Body::Reptile), the monster with most votes is monster_id: 11",
...]
```

I am using Rails 6 and postgres so I have the option to use ActiveRecord, for which I have a slight preference, but I realize this likely needs raw sql.

I understand the answer is very likely an extension of the one given in this question, where they do a similar thing with less attributes, but I can't seem to add the extra complexity needed to accommodate increased number of columns in play.
[sql: select most voted items from each user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605376/sql-select-most-voted-items-from-each-user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, you can use `distinct on` and aggregation:

```
select distinct on (body_id, power_id, body_type) 
    body_id, power_id, body_type, monster_id, count(*) cnt_votes
from votes
group by body_id, power_id, body_type, monster_id
order by body_id, power_id, body_type, count(*) desc
```